# Trouble saving chemical names in mysql database (parenthesis and square brackets)

Tags: mysql, database, parentheses, brackets, chemistry

I am trying to save chemical names in mysql databsave and have tried various file formats, such as csv (both with and without "" around all the strings), opendocument format, xls etc but it keeps returning errors such as column count does not match the database.

this is an example of the chemical name. `(2S)-7-[[6-O-(6-Deoxy-alpha-L-mannopyranosyl)-beta-D-glucopyranosyl]oxy]-2,3-dihydro-5-hydroxy-2-(3-hydroxy-4-methoxyphenyl)-4H-1-benzopyran-4-one`

Also i am using utf8_unicode_ci collation

Comment: There is no reason why an IUPAC chemical name, e.g. `1,4-butanediol` should present any problem for MySQL to store.  Please give us a reproducible problem.

Comment: *"column count does not match the database*" Would you show us the `CREATE TABLE` script and your `INSERT` query?

Comment: Can you provide us what you have tried and the **exact** errors you get ?

Comment: Sorry guys, the information was very vague and so wasn't expecting to get an answer here. For some reason the excel CSV was the issue. Ran that file with a third party csv to sql software (exportiser pro) and uploaded that and the issues resolved. must have been an issue with a delimiter or something.

Answer (score 0):

Ran the CSV through a third party csv to sql generator and resolved the issue.